# Hide sid in webform confirmation page

Tags: 7, webforms

I am using webform for contact us page.

Once form is successfully submitted, I have redirected it to a thank you page.

But the URL of thank you page keeps adding webform sid, like given below:

http://localhost/test/thank-you?sid=1234

I want to hide the sid from URL.

I am using custom redirect URL in form settings.

Comment: First of all, to try to figure out a solution - why do you want to remove it?

Comment: I dont need that

Comment: Sid is there to get submission information on confirmation page, https://www.drupal.org/node/1616014. as asnwered below better to redirect to custom confirmation page.

Comment: @arpitr...that is also not working

Answer (score 1):

No you can not ignore the "sid" from submission confirmation page.

### Yes you can create a separate thank you page and redirect to that page.

You can install this modules:

->     rules

->     webform rules

Now add a rule that redirects the user to your URL after a webform submission.

---

Using hook_form_alter(), and set the override there.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'my_form') {
     $form['#submit'][] = 'my_submit_handler';
  }
}

function my_submit_handler(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'home';
}
```

---

Refer [Redirect Drupal Webform Submissions](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/webform-redirect/)

Comment: I dont want to do custom code

Comment: Have you tried  webform rules module.

Answer (score 1):

If you Use any of the two then it wont show SID in URL.

```
node/<yournodeid>/webform/configure
```

[image]

Comment: I used custom url as 'thank-you' but it still showing as www.example.com/thank-you?sid=12345

Comment: can you create a URL other than thank-you and check?

Comment: That will not change anything since thank-you isn't a reserved word

Comment: Thats completly strange, as I tested with both, it doesnt show sid in URL.

Comment: cleared cache as well

Comment: can you try to create a new webform and give a try